# The classical Gauss sum

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

This is a problem from dummit and foote 14.7.11[image]

I solved everything except b). I tried hard but couldn't solve it. I'm trying to using sum of pth root of unity is 0. But there are $p$ terms in lagrange resolvant. So this won't work.

Please help me with b) (why lagrange resolvant $(\zeta_p,1)=-1$).

Comment: I may be wrong, but, from a) follows that $\eta_0+\eta_1+1$ is the sum of all $p$-th roots of unity, so must be zero.

Comment: @Mindlack The problem is $\eta_0+\eta1$ is not equal to$(\zeta_p,1)$

Comment: Dummit defined $(\zeta_p,1)=\sum_0^{p-1}\sigma^i\zeta_p$. It was define inside 14 7 section   if instead of that if lagrange resolvant is defined as$(\zeta_p,1)=\sum_0^{p-2}\sigma^i\zeta_p$. Then it's done as @Mindlack pointed out. I checked other books to see if it's a typo. But I didn't find it anywhere

Comment: Seeing as $\sum_{i=0}^{p-2}{\sigma^i(\zeta_p)}=-1$, you should take take this sum as definition of $(\zeta_p,1)$ and assume there is a typo.

Comment: @rain1 Nope. It doesn't